# Error of duplicated rownames although there are no duplicates

Tags: r, gene, ensembl

I have a data frame that I want to switch its row names from EnsembleID (GENEID) to gene symbol (SYMBOL). When I try to switch, I get this error:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
 Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

The code I'm using works for other similar data frames. Only this one is giving me trouble. There are no duplicates in the row names, I checked, so the source of this error is strange.

This is the code:

```
GetSymbols <- function(df) {   # Switch from geneID format to Symbol format
  
  ensembl.genes = as.vector(rownames(df))
  geneIDs = ensembldb::select(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86, keys= ensembl.genes, keytype = "GENEID", columns = c("SYMBOL","GENEID"))
  dupli = duplicated(geneIDs$GENEID)
  geneIDs = geneIDs[!dupli,]
  rownames(geneIDs) = geneIDs$GENEID
  rownames(df) = geneIDs$SYMBOL
  return(df)
  
}

#Calling the function:
 df = GetSymbols(df)
```

##### A sample of the dataframe:

```
structure(list(logFC = c(0.362414024114299, 0.270660335317552, 
0.250197714648158, 0.355106754020497, 0.860436247608723, 0.331838240496886, 
0.642000001979217, -0.506238094622956, 0.199130048525963, 0.226010606161764, 
-0.300273572714138, 0.763447672404514, -0.282220097838676, 0.686284440644756, 
0.209266959343866, 0.201216572039244, 0.467207891400503, 0.207476905368996, 
0.548263917432251, 0.582095719576479, 0.167369145307915, -0.239886539805618, 
-0.133088162158502, 0.432528267703316, -0.232843401197013), AveExpr = c(2.63663927914016, 
6.23730774047258, 6.74130527553022, 6.51256660562955, 3.51386518575641, 
0.962682352871946, 3.60110717340049, -1.07537043066235, 4.55672701732791, 
3.96125159652725, 1.20473881401599, 1.72955742088622, 2.10495435034315, 
2.95446094011986, 4.31205976523475, 4.85412008885978, 4.09171246258306, 
3.94681319329962, 6.27193781389662, 0.936821016422818, 7.97270280545117, 
2.4470079966345, 5.75991260844846, 3.84225682530045, 3.35515997418382
), t = c(5.15993300980101, 4.74644046948475, 4.67895886939685, 
4.65270476519835, 4.39369295809775, 4.51083389626156, 4.20489542862464, 
-4.49987927160777, 4.1096966271885, 4.03273843222089, -4.09143780518073, 
4.07713970281633, -3.99157698713235, 3.97814493972727, 3.94402861982903, 
3.92673590933521, 3.92436825669156, 3.90538427413924, 3.89364498564491, 
3.93360332510695, 3.80233390398449, -3.76935782400013, -3.7013905266149, 
3.68313224298669, -3.68114307289328), P.Value = c(4.50582660244125e-07, 
3.21245260466636e-06, 4.37260426507432e-06, 4.92523952290176e-06, 
1.54869545509172e-05, 9.2842399715271e-06, 3.45373717288344e-05, 
9.74370585569957e-06, 5.12014322967072e-05, 7.00192255628614e-05, 
5.51721193906694e-05, 5.84844087520547e-05, 8.26184479488647e-05, 
8.71763749953859e-05, 9.9850615705057e-05, 0.000106924308803713, 
0.000107929018751166, 0.000116314737750083, 0.000121805424073131, 
0.000104060063751203, 0.000173710084683786, 0.000197140244520663, 
0.000255164374909145, 0.000273300166932535, 0.000275347732934516
), adj.P.Val = c(0.00727510763230165, 0.0198807293341929, 0.0198807293341929, 
0.0198807293341929, 0.0357217668827299, 0.0262203124576875, 0.06970505049172, 
0.0262203124576875, 0.0858444785191522, 0.09421086799483, 0.0858444785191522, 
0.0858444785191522, 0.0968123298197961, 0.0968123298197961, 0.0968123298197961, 
0.0968123298197961, 0.0968123298197961, 0.098333518854239, 0.098333518854239, 
0.0968123298197961, 0.130401412989609, 0.138392451653505, 0.150726778618736, 
0.150726778618736, 0.150726778618736), B = c(5.59649208873277, 
4.23844568248881, 3.95926511142815, 3.85011503575047, 2.70095619489428, 
2.52151007226572, 2.02920447371096, 1.82077681362955, 1.73104697407381, 
1.44381690648743, 1.32264026808754, 1.26349133643967, 1.17476645994761, 
1.17423988785926, 1.13844103561967, 1.07813935334313, 1.06670248721183, 
1.0004861785984, 0.949862540556422, 0.634079467108277, 0.620590447127368, 
0.489071423128816, 0.29054426889472, 0.254833988789798, 0.246174538031329
)), row.names = c("ENSG00000188938", "ENSG00000182768", "ENSG00000174579", 
"ENSG00000119523", "ENSG00000271798", "ENSG00000204923", "ENSG00000281910", 
"ENSG00000271092", "ENSG00000153767", "ENSG00000116903", "ENSG00000168101", 
"ENSG00000206834", "ENSG00000180035", "ENSG00000251733", "ENSG00000058729", 
"ENSG00000132467", "ENSG00000212464", "ENSG00000115561", "ENSG00000230669", 
"ENSG00000206612", "ENSG00000275272", "ENSG00000162139", "ENSG00000143889", 
"ENSG00000207233", "ENSG00000119878"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is extremely helpful when doing immune deconvolution. I used quanTIseq and it said my row names are duplicated while all of my row names are unique. However, after removing all the ids with the duplicated() function, the immune deconvolution worked! May I know what magic duplicated() do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer shortly after posting this question:

```
ensembl.genes <- rownames(df)
geneIDs <- ensembldb::select(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86, keys= ensembl.genes, keytype = "GENEID", columns = c("SYMBOL","GENEID"))
dupli = duplicated(geneIDs$SYMBOL)
geneIDs = geneIDs[!dupli,]
ind = intersect(rownames(df), geneIDs$GENEID)
df = df[ind,]
rownames(df) = geneIDs$SYMBOL
```

Comment: Can you please mark this as an accepted answer if it works for you?